# @ControllerAvice Exception Handler does not work Internal Server Error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, controller

I'm implementing a global Exception Handler with 
***Spring Boot*** @ControllerAdivce 
***in Kotlin*** with ***Gradle***

```
class SensorTypeNotFoundException(message: String) : RuntimeException(message)
```

if I *throw SensorTypeNotFoundException*, I have 500 Internal Server Error

I can't understand why Spring Boot doesn't see my ExceptionController.

Can anyone help please?

This is my CustomExceptionController:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
class CustomExceptionController {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass.name)

    enum class ErrorKeys {
        ***
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception::class)
    fun handleException(exception: Exception): ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> {
        ***
    }

    private fun createExceptionResponseEntity(exception: Exception): ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> {
        ***
        }
    }

    private fun buildResponse(message: String?, errorKey: ErrorKeys, httpStatus: HttpStatus): ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> {
        ***
        )

        return ResponseEntity(responseEntity, responseEntity.status)
    }
}
```

build.gradle.kts:

```
...
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.1.6.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.7.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.2.71"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.2.71"
}
...
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, I've solved the problem

The problem was, that in my Controller Class the return value was `<List<Any>>`, but it should be `ResponseEntity<List<Any>>`

Answer (score 0):

Create separate class annotated with `@RestControllerAdvice`, put your `@ExceptionHandler` annotated method there and extend above-mentioned class with `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`. You can also specify `basePackages` attribute of `@RestControllerAdvice` to limit the handler execution to certain controllers only.

Comment: Still the same error.
I've done what you've said
But now I have an empty class
`
class CustomExceptionController: ResponseEntityExceptionHandler()`
What is the purpose of that class?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide Response Status specific Exception Handler.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
@ExceptionHandler
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleInternalServerError(Exception e) { 

  //Handler Snippet

}
```

Hope this helps you..!!

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
The problem is, that ExceptionHandler Method wasn't called at all. 
But if I provide Response Status specific Exception ***Class***, then it works.
But then the Class "CustomExceptionController" doesn't have any purpose.